# Correct use of "before" & "from"?

Tags: prepositions, time

I came across this sentence in a newspaper:

> Five minutes from the end I didn't think we could win this game.We deserved to win this
>   championship.

I am confused as to why he uses *from the end*. I think it should be *before the end*, or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From** a point in time can mean starting *before* that point or starting *after* that point, and the context will generally make it clear which. So in your example the listener will interpret *from* as meaning *before*. But in the following example, the future tense tells the listener to interpret *from* as meaning *after*:

- Three weeks from today I'll be living in Berlin.

If you think your statement may be ambiguous, then it's best to use *before* or *after*. For example:

- The fire alarm started ringing ten minutes from the end of the match

is ambiguous, although most people would probably interpret it as *before*.

Comment: it is still confusing

Comment: In your example, *five minutes from the end* and *five minutes before the end* are interchangeable. The context is that of football player talking after the game about how he felt 5 minutes before it finished, so there is no ambiguity. Usually the context in which the word *from* occurs will be unambiguous enough for the listener to correctly interpret if it means *before* or *after*. Sometimes, however, the word *from* may be ambiguous. In such circumstances it's best to use the more precise word.